# Why const is ignored in auto keyword on constant reference

Tags: c++, auto

```
int main()
{

    int a = 10;
    const int &b = a;
    int &c = b; //gives error : C should a  reference to a const b 
    auto d = b; // why const is ignored here?
    d = 15;
    cout << a << d;
}
```

In c++ Primer, it's mentioned that "**const in reference type is always low-level** " Then how come `auto d = b` is not constant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the type deduction rules for `auto` deduce to an object type. You are copy initializing a new `int` from the one referenced by `b`.

That's by design. We want to create new **objects** without explicitly specifying their type. And more often than not, it's a new object that is a copy some other object. Had it deduced to a reference, it would defeat the intended purpose.

If you want the deduced type to be a reference when the initializer is a reference, then that is accomplished with a placeholder of `decltype(auto)`:

```
decltype(auto) d = b; // d and b now refer to the same object
d = 15; // And this will error because the cv-qualifiers are the same as b's
```

Answer (score 2):

For `auto d = b`, you're declaring `d` as non-reference. That means `d` will be a new object copied from `b`, then the reference part of `b` will be ignored, after that, the const-ness is ignored too. So the type of `d` is `int`.

You can declare `d` as reference explicitly, then the const-ness of `b` won't be ignored. e.g.

```
auto& d = b; // the type of d is const int &
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the deducted type is as an `int`, not an `int&`.

That means `d` is not a reference.